# Webhook listening in Delphi

Tags: delphi, webhooks, gupshup

I am trying to set up an application that will receive the web hooks from the WhatsApp-GupShup API in Delphi.
I have worked on API's before, but not on web hooks so some guidance will be much appreciated.

I have set up a Web Module that hosts an API and have created an Action URL to test, but when I use it in the GupShup API, none of my breakpoints fire and I get 'Callback set failed' when I test the URL.
If I try access the URL from my browser, it works and my breakpoints fire.
I have read on here that GupShup will send a GET request to the URL, with parameters for a demo bot, but as stated above my breakpoints don't fire, so I am at a standstill.
Does anyone have an idea on what my situation could be, and any advice on trying to receive web hooks from a Delphi application?

Comment: Your Web Module is accessible from the Internet?

Answer (score 1):

> If I try access the URL from my browser, it works

The browser and the Web module are running in the same network so the GET request from the browser triggers the web module action.

If the GET request is sent from GupShup, it will not reach your web module unless the computer is accessible for incoming connectionns from the Internet.

(How to make a web application accessible from the Internet is a different topic.)